# Problems understanding JJG's IA diagrams

Tags: information-architecture, diagramming

I want to use [JJG's visual vocabulary](http://www.jjg.net/ia/visvocab/) to construct the diagram of a web page. However, I cannot fully understand some of its components. For example, the conditional selector is used when a user action generates one of a number of results for a given path. According to this logic, I cannot see why he does not use it in the following example:

[image]

Also I cannot understand why the results page is not represented as a pagestack since it is defined as a "group of functionally identical pages whose navigational properties are immaterial to the macrostructure of the site"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the Conditional Selector when you have *at least one of possibly many links to non-same objects*.**

---

The Conditional Selector element can be used when user action generates one or more results for a given path. Like this, where the Archive Index might have links for each of the months.

[image: multiple optional branches]

Alternatively, since this is a case where each of the child pages are of the same type, you would be better off representing the same concept with a simple stack. Using both a Conditional Selector and a Page Stack is redundant.

[image: multiple optional branches, all of the same kind]

Where you do want to use the Conditional Selector element is when you have multiple optional branches, of which you're certain to have at least one.

[image: Product page, with optional child pages]

Although, if there is the possibility that *none* of the child pages exist to be linked to then you should instead use Conditional Connectors:

[image: Parent page connects via dashed lines]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this, but I'll throw out a guess.

**The ability to search, browse the archive, or reach any of the second-level pages is not conditional based on a *system* state**. You could argue that it's conditional based on the *user's* state of mind ("what's my favorite page? oh, Search is..."), but that's out of scope of this tool.

In a conditional scenario, **the user enters via one entry point** and is guided to one of many options by the system; here, the user has all options available to them. If the "Search" page were restricted to particular users, for example, or only available at certain times--and users were directed to some other state when it wasn't available--it would be appropriate to use a conditional selector here.

As for your last question--though there are multiple *results*, I didn't see this system as having multiple result *pages* (rather, multiple results per page).

Sound about right? I'm totally new to this vocabulary, so please correct me if I'm totally off base.